# Redstone Mapper stuck on pub get

Tags: dart, redstone.dart

I added [redstone_mappe](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/redstone_mapper)r in my dependencies and run pub get then it got stuck on resolving dependencies...

Here's my pubspec.yaml

```
name: sample
version: 0.0.1
description: SAMPLE
author: Joes
homepage: http://www.joes.com/
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.5.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  appengine: '>=0.3.0 <0.4.0'
  browser: '>=0.10.0 <0.11.0'
  polymer: '>=0.16.0 <0.17.0'
  paper_elements: '>=0.7.0 <0.8.0'
  redstone: '>=0.6.0-beta.1 <0.7.0'
  redstone_mapper: '0.2.0-beta.1 <0.3.0'
  shelf: '>=0.6.0 <0.7.0'
  shelf_static: '>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'
  shelf_rpc: '>=0.0.0 <0.1.0'
  route_hierarchical: '>=0.6.0 <0.7.0'
  sass: '>=0.4.0 <0.5.0'
  dartson: '>=0.2.0 <0.3.0'
dev_dependencies:
  test: any
transformers:
  - sass/inlined_sass_transformer
  - dartson
  - polymer:
      entry_points: web/index.html
  - $dart2js:
      minify: true
      $exclude: bin/**.dart
      $include: '**/*.polymer.bootstrap.dart'
  - test/pub_serve:
      $include: test/**_test{.*,}.dart
```

This happens when i run pub get with redstone_mapper, but without redstone_mapper it works fine

```
Joe's-Mac-mini:sample joe$ pub get
Resolving dependencies... (1:7.6s) 
Resolving dependencies... (1:9.4s) 
Resolving dependencies... (1:24.1s)
```

Comment: I tried it an it worked fine for me. Do you have any other contraints in you `pubspec.yaml` file, like SDK version, or `dev_dependencies`?

Comment: yes, I added my full pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redstone_mapper` `0.2.0-beta.1` isn't compatible with `test`. But I haven't yet found why. The error message I get doesn't help either.

**Update**
According to this message it looks like `redstone_mapper` depends on a too old `analyzer` version

```
Resolving dependencies... (2.0s) 
Incompatible version constraints on analyzer:
- redstone_mapper 0.2.0-beta.1 depends on version >=0.15.6 <0.23.0
- test 0.12.0-beta.2 depends on version >=0.23.0 <0.25.0
```

but the `pubspec.yaml` in the GitHub repo of  `redstone_mapper` shows `analyzer: '>=0.15.6 <0.26.0'` which would also allow `0.25.0`.
Maybe `redstone_mapper` was deployed with a different `pubspec.yaml` or there might be a bug in `pub`.

See also this open issue https://github.com/redstone-dart/redstone_mapper/issues/10

Comment: Thanks, I think i will remove test for now.